# RPM spec files in version control system

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, rpm, specifications

I faced with task of building RPM packets from sources of c++ (but it may be any other language) project controlled with Git. And my question is where should I store ".spec" files for this task? Should it be stored independently of project main sources or be included in them?

This task is complicated by the condition that I'm participating in different projects and use different version control systems: SVN, Git, Mercurial. So I'm trying to find most common and convenient solution without reference to capabilities of specific version control systems.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295860/version-controlling-rpm-spec-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you participate in these projects directly, it looks reasonable to have .spec somewhere in the main source repository. It's just one more file after all, keeping it there requires nothing special from VCS.

If you are to maintain packages for third-party projects, I'd recommend to have separate repo(s) structured like https://github.com/RussianFedora and https://github.com/RussianFedora/unzip This structure just happened to be quite simple and comfortable - you have in one repo your spec file, necessary patches to build for distributions of choice, checksums of upstream sources used.

Comment: @HapKoM, as someone participating in [Debian](http://www.debian.org), I concur: it's considered bad practice for upstreams to provide their own "debianization" as this is considered to be a task for the downstream (the distro maintainers).  So if you consider yourself the downstream for the package go ahead and provide the spec file, otherwise let downstreams decide how to package your stuff. Another approach is to keep the spec file as a reference, say, under a "contrib" directory.